# Call URL from .net without validate the HTTP potocol

Tags: .net, https

I need to create HTTPS call a to remote server that return a data 
the response of that server dose not include a valid HTTP protocol
and i am getting that error

System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

i all ready did that 
[useUnsafeHeaderParsing](http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000556.html)

but that did not help probably because the HTTP protocol is implement so badly

can i tell .net to skip the validation at all 
or use a class that will not validate the HTTP protocol

when i am using a browser i can see the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the end i did have chaise and i wrote some simple code in VB6  
I turn it to a DLL registered that DLL and add referens to .net project 
he made the call fro me VB6 dose not preform HTTP protocol validation 
ugly but working

```
Option Explicit

Dim UrlStr As String

Public Sub InitUrlStr(ByVal pUrlStr As String)
   UrlStr = pUrlStr
End Sub

Public Function SendHttpsRequest(ByVal pXml As String) As String
   Dim WinHttp
   Dim PostData

   Set WinHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

   PostData = pXml

   WinHttp.Open "GET", UrlStr & PostData, False

   WinHttp.Send ' Send request using https
   SendHttpsRequest = WinHttp.responseText  ' assign to local variable

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) callback to ignore certificate validation errors:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

This is a static property which could be set before performing the HTTP request.

Comment: this will tell the server to ignore the Certificate but not the http potocol

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a problem on the other side of the server.  I would be willing to bet that you are not getting through to the other site at all.  If you're talking to a standard Apache or IIS server, they do a pretty good job of implementing HTTP.  Your connection may be interrupted.  Try doing your operation using a web browser and see if it works.

Comment: when i am using a web browser it is working fine.
In the other side it an application probably been waiting in c 
that implement the HTTP protocol by them self no a IIS or Apache

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a fairly simple protocol on top of TCP. You can use a plain socket, and send the `GET` command yourself.